# Should I run dotnet publish on test projects in build pipeline if I want to run them in release pipeline?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines

I have some integration and ui test projects (*.csproj) in my repository.

I understand I need to publish the test assemblies to build artifacts in order to run them later in Release pipeline.

My question is:

How should I pickup the test assemlies?

1. from a build output
2. or should run `dotnet publish tests/MyE2ETests.csproj --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tests`

See last step of this build pipeline

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'


- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish web app'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: True
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'
    zipAfterPublish: True

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish web app artifacts'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app' 
    artifactName: 'App'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish tests artifacts'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: ???
    artifactName: 'Tests'
```

Comment: Hi Liero, I have updated my answer, could you please check it and kindly let me know the result? I am looking forward to hearing from you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a build pipeline and use the following pre-defined **ASP.NET Core** template,
[image]
you will get the pre-configured build pipeline including *DotNet restore step, DotNet build step, DotNet test step, DotNet publish step and then finally publish them as build artifacts*, as below.
[image]
See: [Build, test, and deploy .NET Core apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive) for more guidance.

**Update**>>If you want to run tests in release pipeline, you need to add a copy file to copy *.csproj to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) and then use publish build artifact task to publish it to artifacts.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    Contents: '**/*[Tt]ests/*.csproj'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish tests artifacts'
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/tests'
    artifactName: 'Tests'
```

Comment: The question was about running tests in release pipeline, not in a build pipeline. E.g. E2E tests, Integration Tests, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Well, obviously I need the test dlls in release pipeline, not just csproj. Actually I don't need .csproj and source code at all. The question is whether I should run just `dotnet build` on the test project and copy build output folder, or I should run `dotnet publish` and copy publish output.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you run just dotnet build on the test project in build pipeline, you need to copy the build output folder.

Comment: Well that's what I mentioned in my question. My question still remains unanswered :(

Answer (score 1):

I use a simple CopyTask to copy the unit test build output to the staging folder. The important thing is to set `flattenFolders = false` (default) to preserve the folder structure, since the build output contains Nuget packages in different locations that dotnet test will look for when it is run.

The build output in .NET Core+ is a deeply nested folder structure. Therefore, I have create a template that searches for the unit test dll inside the folder structure and returns the containing folder path. I store it in a variable `resultfolder`. This approach removes the upper levels of the folder structure so you get a clean artifact to download.

```
#search bin subfolders to find the content:
- template: ../Tasks/find-containing-folder.yml  # Template reference
  parameters: 
    condition: variables['doUnitTest']
    folderPathToSearch: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\${{ parameters.unitTestProjectName }}\bin\Release'
    filename: ${{ parameters.unitTestProjectName }}.dll

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy unit test project build output to artifact staging folder'
  condition: eq(variables['doUnitTest'], true)
  inputs:
    sourceFolder: '$(resultfolder)'
    targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/UnitTest'
```

find-containing-folder.yml template:

```
# returns the full path of the first folder found containing the file.
# returns the result in a variable called resultfolder.
# condition parameter is a workaround because template references don't allow conditions. Also, string has to be used, booleans don't work.
# (this is used to navigate through the target framework and runtime identifier subfolders to find the output.
# the folders are determined by what the csproj file contains.)
parameters:
- name: condition
  type: string 
  default: true

- name: folderPathToSearch
  type: string

- name: filename
  type: string

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Find containing folder'
  condition: eq(${{ parameters.condition }}, true)
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        $folderPath = "${{ parameters.folderPathToSearch }}"
        Write-Host "Searching folder: " $folderPath

        $searchResult = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath -Recurse -Filter '${{ parameters.filename }}' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Directory

        Write-Host "searchResult: " $searchResult

        if($searchResult -like "*$folderPath*")
        {
        Write-Host "Found build output folder: " $searchResult
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=resultfolder]$searchResult"
        }
        else 
        {
        Write-Host "Build output not found." 
        exit 1
        }
```